# Response Code From Server

Tags: java

```
public static boolean testConnection() {
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "some proxy name");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "some port");
        URL a = new URL("http://" + Variables.serverName + ":" +           Variables.serverPort      + "/DeviceCloud");
        urlString = a.toExternalForm()+"/";
        System.out.println(urlString);
        System.out.println("http://" + Variables.serverName + ":" + Variables.serverPort + "/DeviceCloud");
        URLConnection conn = a.openConnection();
        int respCode = ((HttpURLConnection) conn).getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(respCode);
        if (respCode >= 500) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works fine if server reachable. But if server not reachable means its taking long time.
Its not showing any output.But actually the server machine is pinging from client also.
what could be right solution to get the status

Comment: Pinging does not mean you can open a HTTP connection to the same server.  Can you provide more detail on the network?  For example, do you have to go through a proxy to get to the host?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a timeout with the [setConnectTimeout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) method:

```
try {
    HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) a.openConnection();
    httpconn.setConnectTimeout(10000); //10 seconds timeout

    return (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // You can get an output here if it timed out
    return false;
}
```